# Is there any way to determine whether the same individual who have visited your website also downloaded and installed your phone app?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ipad, mobile

Currently, I'm looking to see if there is a way to sync the information we've obtained through an online site with the information we use on a phone application.

All I need to know is that the user that visited our site is the same user that is using our phone application, No stats and preferably no one needs to enter a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get that from Apple, because of their history with privacy concerns, but you could do something like generate an identifying number in your app, that your web site asks for, that would tie the two together.  Of course, you'd have to make allowances if your app is deleted from the device, then re-installed, to either make sure you're generating the same number, or other such solution as befits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that would come to my mind is Google Analytics, available for different platforms and services (i.e. Youtube, etc). You would have to go through [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/) to figure out a way on how to track a particular customer visit across several location/platforms.

See [Hello Analytics example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) of Google Analytics API 
See [Data Feed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataReferenceDataFeed)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so far I've answered my own question for androids. Apparently you can pass a referrer param through  google play which actually allows your app to receive the parameter and they even have an app that test this functionality.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.stevemiller.android.referrertest

now I have yet to test this, nor is it a possible solution for iOS.

Comment: A decent article for 2013. Don't know how much of it is applicable now though.

http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/22260809-An-Introduction-to-Mobile-App-Attribution

Comment: for ios you'd need to use fingerprinting to pass a param through the App Store. Deep-linking sdks like [branch.io](http://branch.io) will take care of this and the edge cases on both ios and android